# Use sed to prefix and suffix multiple strings per line

Tags: sed, sql

I have a .sql file with some 15,000,000 INSERT commands on each line, which look something like this:

`INSERT INTO tableName (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8) VALUES ('Jan  7 2018 12:33PM', 'R', 'essential-app', '15952008002', 'Jan  7 2018 12:30PM', '0', 'E', NULL);`

I want to wrap both date/time values so they look like `STR_TO_DATE('Jan  7 2018 12:33PM',%b  %d %Y %h:%i%p)` - preserving the original value, of course.

I have used sed to make small changes to files before, but never something as complicated as this. How do I go about targeting both those date/time values, and how do I go about adding strings to both the beginning and end of the matched strings?
Add to the beginning: `STR_TO_DATE(`
Add to the end: `,%b  %d %Y %h:%i%p)`
*Can* it be done in one sed command, or do I need a sed command for each date/time value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -r -e 's/'\''[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\s+[0-9]+\s[0-9]{4}\s+[0-9]+:[0-9][0-9][AP]M'\''/STR_TO_DATE(&, '\''%b  %d %Y %h:%i%p'\'')/g'
```

Notes:

- `'\''` is how you insert a single-quote in a single-quoted string.
- The regexp matches:

  - a single-quote `'`, followed by
  - an uppercase letter and two lowercase letters `Jan` (or `Feb` etc.),
  - one or more spaces, one or more digits, a space, four digits `7 2018`,
  - one or more spaces, one or more digits, a colon, two digits, an A or P, an M `12:30PM`, and finally
  - another single-quote `'`.

This transforms

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8) VALUES ('Jan  7 2018 12:33PM', 'R', 'essential-app', '15952008002', 'Jan  7 2018 12:30PM', '0', 'E', NULL);
```

into

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('Jan  7 2018 12:33PM', '%b  %d %Y %h:%i%p'), 'R', 'essential-app', '15952008002', STR_TO_DATE('Jan  7 2018 12:30PM', '%b  %d %Y %h:%i%p'), '0', 'E', NULL);
```

I took the liberty of wrapping the format string in single-quotes. I hope this is what was intended.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks so much! And yes, you are correct about wrapping the format string in quotes as well - good catch!